# Error in exporting attribute table into ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, export

I have an attribute table of about 2.5 million rows and 10 columns that I am trying to export as dbf or text file but i keep getting the error message,

> An error occurred exporting the table, a column was specified that
>   does not exist

How do i resolve this using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2?

Comment: Hey Alvin - maybe give the export another try again using 'Text File' as the output type, when exporting from the attribute table (Export Data dialog box)? I'd be interested to see if the export can succeed in another format.

Comment: How wide is the table?  dBase-III is limited to 2Gb, which would mean a width of 860 bytes or wider would exceed the capability of the format.

Comment: Often closing and reopening ArcGIS helps... Did you check if there are special characters (e.g. spaces) in the columnnames?

Comment: thanks for your response.. i have tried ALL the output format, they all give same error message.

Comment: I have also closed and reopened the ArcGIS serally but didnt solve the issue. It is a line attribute table computed from the Network Analyst solver, so no special characters are in it.

Comment: @Vince, i am not sure i clearly understood what you mean by width of table, but I have a table with 2.53million rows and 10 column fields.

Comment: The attribute tables comes from an shapefile, right? Does this shapefile contains special characters?

Comment: @Iris, yes its from a line shape file outputted after running a network analyst tool. one of the column names has an underscore like this Travel_Time. There's no other special characters. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Underscore shouldn't be a problem, but very long shapefile names or shapefile names with dots or umlauts produce strange errors.

Comment: shapefile name is just...  Lines

Comment: dBase is a fixed width format.  Ten columns with 80-character strings would have a width  of 800 bytes.  Ten columns of 100-character strings would have a width of 1000.  If you add up the widths of the columns, you have the width of the table.  If your source is shapefile, then a "Save As" shouldn't exceed the limit (though it may be close).  You may just have a corrupt file;Tech Support may be the most appropriate way to verify this.